# Parquet error when joining two dataframes. UnsupportedOperationException: ...PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- pid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- lv: timestamp (nullable = true)
root
 |-- m_pid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- vp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- created: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

If I try to show() any of these 2 dataframes everything is ok, top 20 rows are displayed.
If I try to join these 2 dataframes and show the result (error does not appear at the join transformation, only when calling "show" action)

```
var joined = df1.join(df2, df2("pid") === df1("m_pid")).drop("m_pid")
joined.show()
```

I get an error which I do not understand. It is related to parquet. One of the dataframes is read from a parquet (the other one from text) but if it would be a problem related to reading the data then why does the problem appear only when joining the dataframes, not when showing the individually.

The error is:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 51 in stage 403.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 51.3 in stage 403.0 : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary

...

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary
  at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToDouble(Dictionary.java:60)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getDouble(OnHeapColumnVector.java:354)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:147)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  ... 1 more
```

Does anyone have an ideea what causes the error and how to go around it?

Comment: Maybe the error is in reading the parquet but when calling `show`, only a small amount of rows are read and it's not enough to raise the problem.

Comment: can you share sample data to replicate the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no Ram, it's company data

Comment: Ok Daniel so then saving a previous dataframe as parrquet should generate the issue too. I'll try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @DanieldePaula > the data is sent via an ETL tool to Kafka and then a Spark Consumer takes the data and saves it as parquet in HDFS. The parquet files that were failing the job were saved with a spark consumer so Spark was able to save these files then the same Spark is unable to work with them.
I managed to find a workaround by sending a limited number of columns using the ETL tool. I guess one of the columns that I'm not sending anymore contains data that corrupts the job but again, that data already went through Spark before so it's pretty weird. I'll try to dig deeper when I have time